# Flutter: get different plans from subscription

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, google-play-console, android-inapp-purchase, flutter-in-app-purchase

I have one subscription with 2 plans:

[image]

The IDs I have created in Flutter are these:

```
const List<String> _androidProductIds = <String>[
  'plus',
  'pro',
  'basic', // this is the one
];
```

I have tried adding `basic-month` and `basic-year` but I only get the first one. How could I choose between plans within the same subscription?

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: at the end I created different subscriptions just for this

Comment: how can you apply a developer determined offer in Flutter code for subscriptions?